# ionic-5: Type 'StatusBarOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5, ionic-plugins

In **ionic-5** I'm importing Statusbar with this in **app.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [],
      imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
export class AppModule {}
```

and getting this error:

**Type 'StatusBarOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 others**

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Status Bar plugin if you haven't already:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar

npm install @ionic-native/status-bar
```